# Magento changing sort order on filtered navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, sorting

I am using a custom theme based on RWD and when I select an element in the layered navigation (or multiple elements) the order of the product listing is changed from asc to desc. Can anyone suggest why this may be or a fix?

Do I need to do an XML update in every category page to keep the asc order? I already have local.xml telling the category to sort in asc order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you changed in "catalog_category_default" tag in local.xml.

like this :

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <action method="setDefaultDirection"><string>asc</string></action>
        <action method="setDefaultOrder"><string>position</string>                   </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

Hope this help of you.